# How to create dynamic Dynamic Fields in OTRS Community Edition?

Tags: otrs

I've created a dropdown dynamic field for Agent's new email ticket screen in ((otrs)) community edition. Now, I need to show a new dropdown dynamic field after the first dropdown item choice. Is this possible? If not, is there any addon for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a process. Check out the OTRS Admin manual on Process Management.